# i want to store iphone name with their price in excel sheet.for same iphone name sore in one excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium

go to flipkart search for iphone  for same i phone name create one excel sheet for another iphone name create another excel sheet.

Code look like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> uniquename = new HashSet<String>();
        ArrayList<String[]> data1 = new  ArrayList<String[]>();
        Map<String,List<String[]> > hashmap = new HashMap<String,List<String[]> >();
        data1.add( new String[] {"Apple iPhone 8 Plus (Space Grey, 64 GB)","56000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone 6 (Grey, 128 GB)","47000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone XS (Space Grey, 512 GB)","28000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone XS (Space Grey, 512 GB)","29000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone 7 Plus (Gold, 128 GB)","19000"});
        data1.add(new String[] {"Apple iPhone 7 Plus (Gold, 128 GB)","18000"});
        for(String[] data:data1) {
            uniquename.add(data[0].replace("(", "#").split("#")[0] );
        }

            System.out.println(uniquename);
            System.out.println(uniquename.size());
            System.out.println(data1.size());


            for(String name : uniquename) {
                List<String[]> temp =new ArrayList<String[]>();
                    for(String[] d : data1) {
                        if(name==d[0].substring(0, 19)) {
                            temp.add(d);


                        }
                        hashmap.put(name, temp);
                    }

                    }
            Set keys = hashmap.keySet();
             System.out.println("All keys are: " + keys);

                    List<String[]> value = hashmap.get(keys);
                    for(String[] val : value) {
                        System.out.println(value);      
}
}
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: is there a question involved?

Comment: Welcome, you might want to [edit] your question describing the problem you are facing with the current code.

Comment: yes,why their show null to get value of key

Comment: i want for all apple iphone 6s create a excel sheet,for all apple iphone xs create another sheet